# How can I reuse my dry nails-paints?

Tags: paint, recycling

It is a common issue for females. Nails-paints became dry very quickly. How can I reuse my dry nails-paints?

Comment: When you say "Nails-paints", I assume you mean Nail Varnish? When you say "Re-use" are you trying to refresh a dried-out nail varnish so you can continue to use it, or are you looking for an alternative use for nail varnish that is unusable because it has dried out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding on to @user18894's answer, you could also buy acetone from a beauty shop or drug store. Dip the brush of the nail polish into a bit of acetone, then place it back into the bottle to make the dry polish runny again.

Here are some more suggestions and a step-by-step guide: https://www.wikihow.com/Restore-Thick-Dried-Out-Nail-Polish

Answer (score 1):

You can buy nail polish thinner (from where you buy your nail polish) to make the thickened nail polish runny again.